# loop to fill matrix after certain frequency

Tags: r, for-loop, matrix

My objective is to convert these values into 64 days with 102 (510/5) frequency. There are 510 values per day and I want to pick every fifth value (1,6,11, ... to make a final matrix of 102*64). With the following code:

```
    data <- read.csv(file="voljump.csv", header=FALSE, sep=",")#32640
    mat <- data.matrix(data)
            fin_data <- t(mat)
             days <- nrow(data)#32640
    freq <- 510
    data_5 <- matrix(0, freq, days) 
    for(j in 1:days) {for (i in 1:freq) 
      {data_5[i,j] <- fin_data[(i-1)*4+1 ,j]}}
```

I am getting an error:

> "Error in fin_data[(i - 1) * 5 + 1, j] : subscript out of bounds"

Answer (score 0):

I guess the following code might reach your goal

```
data_5 <- fin_data[seq(1,510,by=5),]
```

Comment: its fine, but its filling only first day. (first 510). the other days are missing

Comment: @M-FaheemAslam what is the dimension of `fin_data`? Isn't it a matrix of size 510*64? I used `fin_data[seq(1,510,by=5), ]`, which takes out the required rows through all columns